# "ErrorMessage=" named parameter of custom attributes for validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I followed a tutorial and made a `custom remote validator` for my application so that it will work even if the javascript is disabled. It works the same as normal `Remote` validations by having a specified `controller` and `action` and the optional `ErrorMessage`.

Here is the full code:

```
public class RemoteEmailCheckAttribute : RemoteAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //get the controller
        Type controller = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller", this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
        if (controller != null)
        {
            MethodInfo action = controller.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name.ToLower() == this.RouteData["controller"].ToString().ToLower());

            if (action != null)
            {
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controller);
                object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
                if (response is JsonResult)
                {
                    object jsonData = ((JsonResult)response).Data;
                    if (jsonData is bool)
                    {
                        return (bool)jsonData ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
    }


    public RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string routeName)
        : base(routeName)
    {

    }


    public RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string action, string controller)
        : base(action, controller)
    {

    }

    public RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string action, string controller, string areaName)
        : base(action, controller, areaName)
    {

    }
}
```

And this is how i set it on my property,

```
[RemoteEmailCheck("IsEmailTaken","Enrollment",ErrorMessage="Email is already in use. Please pick something else")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

**my question is that**, since i will be using this `constructor`:

```
 public RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string action, string controller, string areaName)
 : base(action, controller, areaName)
```

Since the third parameter is actually `string` of any name, how was it able to get the specified `ErrorMessage=" "`?

I have been checking/researching online and read about `Named parameters` but they are somehow different, please clarify it to me.

Comment: Probably when I answered this question I didn't know I can vote for questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating Attributes, Any public non-static read-write fields or properties are named parameters.

For more information see [Creating Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx)

Comment: Oh right , so they can be directly accessed on the constructor?

Comment: When using as attributes, Yes.